# FaceDetect OpenCV2.1 sample, Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: opencv, access-violation, face-detection

I try to run facedetect opencv sample with vs2010.
debug result "Unhandled exception at 0x53fa42bf in facedetect.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

Here is the code 
txt file: http://ebooks-libs.com/backup/facedetect-opencv2.1.txt
cpp file: http://ebooks-libs.com/backup/facedetect.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#define CV_NO_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#ifdef _EiC
#define WIN32
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img,
                   CascadeClassifier& cascade, CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                   double scale);

String cascadeName ="./data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String nestedCascadeName ="./data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    Mat frame, frameCopy, image;
    const String scaleOpt = "--scale=";
    size_t scaleOptLen = scaleOpt.length();
    const String cascadeOpt = "--cascade=";
    size_t cascadeOptLen = cascadeOpt.length();
    const String nestedCascadeOpt = "--nested-cascade";
    size_t nestedCascadeOptLen = nestedCascadeOpt.length();
    String inputName;

    CascadeClassifier cascade, nestedCascade;
    double scale = 1;

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        if( cascadeOpt.compare( 0, cascadeOptLen, argv[i], cascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
            cascadeName.assign( argv[i] + cascadeOptLen );
        else if( nestedCascadeOpt.compare( 0, nestedCascadeOptLen, argv[i], nestedCascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( argv[i][nestedCascadeOpt.length()] == '=' )
                nestedCascadeName.assign( argv[i] + nestedCascadeOpt.length() + 1 );
            if( !nestedCascade.load( nestedCascadeName ) )
                cerr << "WARNING: Could not load classifier cascade for nested objects" << endl;
        }
        else if( scaleOpt.compare( 0, scaleOptLen, argv[i], scaleOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( !sscanf( argv[i] + scaleOpt.length(), "%lf", &scale ) || scale < 1 )
                scale = 1;
        }
        else if( argv[i][0] == '-' )
        {
            cerr << "WARNING: Unknown option %s" << argv[i] << endl;
        }
        else
            inputName.assign( argv[i] );
    }

    if( !cascade.load( cascadeName ) )
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade" << endl;
        cerr << "Usage: facedetect [--cascade=\"<cascade_path>\"]\n"
            "   [--nested-cascade[=\"nested_cascade_path\"]]\n"
            "   [--scale[=<image scale>\n"
            "   [filename|camera_index]\n" ;
        return -1;
    }

    if( inputName.empty() || (isdigit(inputName.c_str()[0]) && inputName.c_str()[1] == '\0') )
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( inputName.empty() ? 0 : inputName.c_str()[0] - '0' );
    else if( inputName.size() )
    {
        image = imread( inputName, 1 );
        if( image.empty() )
            capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( inputName.c_str() );
    }
    else
        image = imread( "lena.jpg", 1 );

    cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );

    if( capture )
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            frame = iplImg;
            if( frame.empty() )
                break;
            if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
                frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
            else
                flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );

            detectAndDraw( frameCopy, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );

            if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                goto _cleanup_;
        }

        waitKey(0);
_cleanup_:
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    }
    else
    {
        if( !image.empty() )
        {
            detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );
            waitKey(0);
        }
        else if( !inputName.empty() )
        {
            /* assume it is a text file containing the
            list of the image filenames to be processed - one per line */
            FILE* f = fopen( inputName.c_str(), "rt" );
            if( f )
            {
                char buf[1000+1];
                while( fgets( buf, 1000, f ) )
                {
                    int len = (int)strlen(buf), c;
                    while( len > 0 && isspace(buf[len-1]) )
                        len--;
                    buf[len] = '\0';
                    cout << "file " << buf << endl;
                    image = imread( buf, 1 );
                    if( !image.empty() )
                    {
                        detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );
                        c = waitKey(0);
                        if( c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q' )
                            break;
                    }
                }
                fclose(f);
            }
        }
    }

    cvDestroyWindow("result");

    return 0;
}

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img,
                   CascadeClassifier& cascade, CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                   double scale)
{
    int i = 0;
    double t = 0;
    vector<Rect> faces;
    const static Scalar colors[] =  { CV_RGB(0,0,255),
        CV_RGB(0,128,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,128,0),
        CV_RGB(255,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,255)} ;
    Mat gray, smallImg( cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1 );

    cvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    resize( gray, smallImg, smallImg.size(), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR );
    equalizeHist( smallImg, smallImg );

t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cascade.detectMultiScale( smallImg, faces,1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,Size(30, 30) );
        //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
        //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
 printf( "detection time = %g ms\n", t/((double)cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.) );
  for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = faces.begin(); r != faces.end(); r++, i++ )
    {
        Mat smallImgROI;
        vector<Rect> nestedObjects;
        Point center;
        Scalar color = colors[i%8];
        int radius;
        center.x = cvRound((r->x + r->width*0.5)*scale);
        center.y = cvRound((r->y + r->height*0.5)*scale);
        radius = cvRound((r->width + r->height)*0.25*scale);
        circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        if( nestedCascade.empty() )
            continue;
        smallImgROI = smallImg(*r);
        nestedCascade.detectMultiScale( smallImgROI, nestedObjects,
            1.1, 2, 0
            //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
            |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
            ,
            Size(30, 30) );
       for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator nr = nestedObjects.begin(); nr != nestedObjects.end(); nr++ )
        {
            center.x = cvRound((r->x + nr->x + nr->width*0.5)*scale);
            center.y = cvRound((r->y + nr->y + nr->height*0.5)*scale);
            radius = cvRound((nr->width + nr->height)*0.25*scale);
            circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        } 
    }
   cv::imshow( "result", img ); 
}
```

Need some help how to resolve it...

Comment: Trace it with VS2010's nice debugging tools, where does the problem occur, which function, which class, which usage style etc.. This way of asking will have no answer.

Answer (score 0):

The access violation error probably means you are accessing a pointer that you haven't set the value for.

If you don't understand how to use the debugger (learn!) put printf("ok1,2,3 ....\n"); liberally through the code and work out how far it's gettign so you can narrow down where the error happens

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too with OpenCV 2.3 on VS2010, even after adjusting the code so that `cascadeName` uses the full path to `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`.

I was able to pinpoint the problem to the line that crashes the application:

```
if( !cascade.load( cascadeName ) )
```

The crash is coming from OpenCV's code and I don't know why it happens.

Comment: I tested under OS X 10.6.8 and OpenCV2 r6123 and it works fine for me. It seems to draw a circle around the ugliest part of the video feed (i.e. my face).

Comment: Yes, I know it works on other platforms. The problem seems to be with the Windows version. Thanks.

Comment: @karlphillip Did you find a solution for this problem?